# After redirect from a controller Yii session not working

Tags: php, redirect, yii

After save a model i want to store a model auto increment id in a session variable and redirect to a view page. When i want to echo that session variable in view page it is not working.

Note: I don't use user login/logout system.

**In config.php**

```
'session' => array(
        'autoStart'=>true,
        'timeout'=>1200,
    ),
```

**In Controller File**

```
if ($model->save()) {
    Yii::app()->session['orderId']=$model->id;
    $this->redirect(array('view', 'id' => $model->id));
}
```

In the controller where i use redirect() if i use render() then it's work. After redirect it's not working.

**In View File**

```
echo Yii::app()->session['orderId'];
```

Please Help Me :(

Answer (score 0):

You can store session data with

```
if ($model->save()) {
Yii::app()->user->setState('orderId', $model->id);
}
```

Get it with

```
echo Yii::app()->user->getState('orderId');
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But it's not work. Are you sure your code will work for guest user? Because i mentioned my question "Note: I don't use user login/logout system."

Answer (score 0):

Try this ,

in your controller

```
if ($model->save()) {
    Yii::app()->user->setState("orderId",$model->id);
     $this->redirect(array('view', 'id' => $model->id));

}
```

//get session variable

```
Yii::app()->user->getState("orderId");
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to add "return" before redirect:

```
return $this->redirect(array('view', 'id' => $model->id);
```